# Pytest - link function\row with local variables (optimization of tests)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pytest

conftest:

```
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def driver():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe")
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    driver.maximize_window()
    yield driver
    driver.quit()


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def wait(driver):
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    return wait
```

example of test:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from variables import *


def test_login(driver, wait):
    driver.get(url)
    original_window = driver.current_window_handle
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, login_btn_ws)))
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(login_btn_ws).click()
    for window_handle in driver.window_handles:
        if window_handle != original_window:
            driver.switch_to.window(window_handle)
            break
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, login_field)))
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(login_field).send_keys(login)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(password_field).send_keys(password, Keys.ENTER)
    wait.until((EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, welcome_field))))
    assert url_check in driver.current_url and welcome_check in driver.find_element_by_xpath(welcome_field).text.lower()
```

I would like to put out from test module to conftest or something like this - two parts of code (see below):

1. `driver.get(url)`
2. ```
        if window_handle != original_window:
            driver.switch_to.window(window_handle)
            break
   ```

   The main problem - that I don't understand how to correctrly define variables like url, original window etc.
   The structure of project for now: conftest in main folder, subfolder with two files: test and variables file which you can see above at example of the test. I apologize for not giving the complete runnable code with variables file.